# Yii CGridView DataProvider

Tags: php, yii

I got 2 models: Project and User. In Project:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
            "users"=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User',
            'projects_users(project_id, user_id)'),
    );
}
```

I want to list all users who are in actual project, $model contain actual project:

```
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->users,
    'columns'=>array(
        'ID',
        'username',
        'displayname',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'email',
        /*
        'password',
        'isAdmin',
        */

        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{delete}',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Unfortuletlly I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/aevers.com/editor/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php on line 107
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because *$model->users* is not a **CActiveDataProvider** : it's an **array** of CActiveRecords.

Try to use a [**CArrayDataProvider**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider) instead :

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-grid',
    'dataProvider'=> new CArrayDataProvider($model->users),
    [...] 
    ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can Group And display the results according to Projects and users in cgridView
Try This Thread [Grouping members](http://groupgridview.demopage.ru/)